# How to test iRate without it being on the Apple App Store yet?

Tags: ios, irate

When I set preview mode on, it shows the alert.  But I'd like to test out the configurations I've set without the app being on the App Store yet.  How can I accomplish this?

I'm getting this error in the logs:

> iRate is checking
>   http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=ca.bunle.id
>   to retrieve the App Store details...
>
> iRate could not find the App Store ID for this application. If the
>   application is not intended for App Store release then you must
>   specify a custom ratingsURL.
>
> iRate could not find your app on iTunes. If your app is not yet on the
>   store or is not intended for App Store release then don't worry about
>   this

I'm guessing I could set a custom ratingsURL and have it return what iRate needs, however I'm hoping there is an easier/faster way I can accomplish testing the configs.

Comment: Have you initialized an appstore id? [iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID = <appstore_id>;

Comment: After setting this property, I'm getting the same results.  Please see  my edited question for the additional line of code.

Comment: When you first run your app, are you getting any errors in the log?  iRate often posts errors if the AppStoreID doesn't work, or stuff like that.

Comment: @AlexanderWinn - Thanks a lot, I forgot about checking the logs.  I've revised the question accordingly.

Comment: I wouldn't swear to this in court, but as I recall all you have to do is set up your app in iTunes Connect.  It doesn't need to be approved and available.  As long as the AppID and such is set up and iTunes Connect is waiting for an upload, I think it should work.

Comment: Cool.  If it works, let me know and I'll re-add that as an answer to this question, so you can flag it as approved.  I'm just not sure enough in my memory to declare it correct without testing, and I'm not at home right now to test it myself.  :P

Comment: This does not work for me. I have set my appleID and I still get the same message